# Help reading an eyeglass prescription: What does "PL" or "PC" mean?

Tags: eye, prescription, glasses, astigmatism

I'm trying to purchase glasses online but I cannot figure out what the Spherical value is for the left eye (OS).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found this:

> Plano - PL - This indicates there is no spherical correction in this
>   eye. A plano lens would have no focusing power or correction to it.

So it's `0`.

Source: [How to Read and Enter Your Eyeglass Prescription](http://www.aclens.com/How-to-Read-Your-Eyeglass-Prescription-c172.html) - aclens.com.